# Extracting files from a sharepoint database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to create a small little program in C# to extract files from a Sharepoint database.  I obtained the code from a search online and I am trying to edit it so that the files are extracted to a specific folder while maintaining the folder from the Sharepoint database.

Specifically, I want the user to enter the name of the server from the form, the name of the database that they are trying to extract files from, and finally the path that they wish to use to extract the files.

I am getting an error when I debug.

The error states: `Could not find a part of the path:`
Regarding this line of code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtdir.Text + "/" + DirName + "/" + LeafName,
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace SPEXTRACTOR
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ENTER_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string DBConnString = "Server=" + txtserver.Text + ";Database=" 
                            + txtDB.Text + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBConnString);
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
      com.CommandText = "SELECT ad.SiteId, ad.Id, ad.DirName," +
          " ad.LeafName, ads.Content" +
          " FROM AllDocs ad, AllDocStreams ads" +
          " WHERE ad.SiteId = ads.SiteId" +
          " AND ad.Id = ads.Id" +
          " AND ads.Content IS NOT NULL" +
          " Order by DirName";


      //SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
      //com.CommandText = "select DirName, LeafName, Content 
        from AllDocStreams, AllDocs 
        where (LeafName like '%.doc' or LeafName like '%.xls' 
               or LeafName like '%.pdf' or LeafName like '%.ppt') 
               and Content is not NULL";


      //com.CommandText = "select DirName, LeafName, Content 
        from AllDocStreams, AllDocs 
        where (LeafName like '%.doc' or LeafName like '%.xls' 
               or LeafName like '%.pdf' or LeafName like '%.ppt') 
               and Content is not NULL";


      SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
        // grab the file's directory and name
        string DirName = (string)reader["DirName"];
        string LeafName = (string)reader["LeafName"];

        if (!Directory.Exists(DirName))
        {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(DirName);
          Console.WriteLine("Creating directory: " + DirName);
        }

        //FileStream fs = new FileStream(DirName + "/" + LeafName
                              , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtdir.Text + "/" + DirName + "/" 
                          + LeafName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        // depending on the speed of your network, 
        //you may want to change the buffer size (it's in bytes)
        int bufferSize = 1000000;
        long startIndex = 0;
        long retval = 0;
        byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];

        // grab the file out of the db one chunk (of size bufferSize) at a time
        do
        {
          retval = reader.GetBytes(4, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
          //retval = reader.GetBytes(2, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
          startIndex += bufferSize;

          writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval);
          writer.Flush();
        } while (retval == bufferSize);

        // finish writing the file
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished writing file: " + LeafName);
      }

      // close the DB connection and whatnots
      reader.Close();
      con.Close();   
    }                   
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug or write out what the value is of your expected full path on that problematic line?

Comment: Example:  If I want the files to be extracted to c:\aa

Comment: I get this error: "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\\aa\\drive_space\\Shared Documents\\ArchivedData.xlsx'.  This is from debugging.

Comment: txtdir.text is the textbox that the user enters the directory they wish to have the files extracted to.  this is in the form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the entire [DoxoEater2](http://runbooks.blogspot.co.uk/p/doxoeater2.html) program used to extract files from a WSS3 database, aka MDF file, but must be mounted in MS SQL.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace DoxoEater2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // WSS 3.0 default DB via SQL 2005 embedded edition.
            //string DBConnString = "Data Source=\\\\.\\pipe\\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\\sql\\query;Database=WSS_Content;Trusted_Connection=yes;Timeout=2000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

            // Or localhost, WSS_Content, typical SQL connection style, TCP/IP listener.
            string DBConnString = "Data Source=localhost;Database=WSS_Content;Trusted_Connection=yes;Timeout=2000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            string DocsQuery = "select [AllDocs].[Id], [AllDocs].[DirName], [AllDocs].[LeafName] from [AllDocs] where dirname <> '' order by dirname;";

            Console.WriteLine("START: " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() + " UTC");

            SqlConnection con;

            try // create a DB connection
            {   
                con = new SqlConnection(DBConnString);
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }

            SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = DocsQuery;

            // readers for SQL queries: 1) which docs? 2) featch binary data per DocID
            SqlDataReader reader, reader2;

            try {   // execute query
                reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (con != null) { con.Close(); }
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
                return;
            }

            while (reader.Read()) { // rows of document ID, name and directory nodes

                // grab the file's directory and name
                Guid FileId = (Guid)reader["Id"];
                string DirName = (string)reader["DirName"];
                string LeafName = (string)reader["LeafName"];

                // create directory for the file if it doesn't yet exist
                if (!Directory.Exists(DirName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DirName);
                    Console.WriteLine("DIR: " + DirName);
                }

                // check if file already exists or not
                if (File.Exists(DirName + "/" + LeafName)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: File Already Exists: " + DirName + "/" + LeafName);
                    continue;
                }

                SqlCommand com2 = con.CreateCommand();
                com2.CommandText = "select content from [AllDocStreams]  where  [AllDocStreams].[Id] = '" + FileId.ToString() + "';";
                Console.WriteLine("SQL: " + com2.CommandText.ToString());

                try
                {   // execute file fetch query
                    reader2 = com2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (con != null) { con.Close(); }
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    return;
                }

                while(reader2.Read()) {

                    // create a filestream to spit out the file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(DirName + "/" + LeafName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);


                    // depending on the speed of your network, you may want to change the buffer size (it's in bytes)
                    int bufferSize = 1048576;
                    long startIndex = 0;
                    long retval = 0;
                    byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // grab the file out of the db one chunk (of size bufferSize) at a time
                    do
                    {
                        retval = reader2.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                        startIndex += bufferSize;

                        writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval);
                        writer.Flush();
                    } while (retval == bufferSize);

                    // finish writing the file
                    Console.WriteLine("FILE: " + LeafName);
                    writer.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                }
                reader2.Close();

            }

            // close the DB connection and whatnots
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("DONE: " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() + " UTC");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell of the same:

```
$Server="localhost"
$db="WSSContent"
$LocalDir="C:\xyz"

$sql = "SELECT ad.SiteId, ad.Id, ad.DirName,
 ad.LeafName, ads.Content
 FROM AllDocs ad, AllDocStreams ads
 WHERE ad.SiteId = ads.SiteId
 AND ad.Id = ads.Id
 AND ads.Content IS NOT NULL
 AND ad.LeafName like '%aspx'
 Order by DirName";


$connectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$db;Connect Timeout=3;"
$con = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection") $connectionString

$con.Open();
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand();
$cmd.CommandText = $sql;
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader();

while ($reader.Read())
{
    # grab the file's directory and name
    $DirName = [string]$reader["DirName"];
    $LeafName = [string]$reader["LeafName"];

    if (-not [System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$LocalDir\$DirName"))
    {
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$LocalDir\$DirName");
        Write-Host "Creating directory: $LocalDir\$DirName"
    }

    $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream "$LocalDir\$DirName\$LeafName" ,'Create','Write','Read';

    $writer = new-object "System.IO.BinaryWriter" $fs;

    # depending on the speed of your network, 
    #you may want to change the buffer size (it's in bytes)
    $bufferSize = 1000000;
    $startIndex = 0;
    $retval = 0;
    $out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize) 
    #
    ## grab the file out of the db one chunk (of size bufferSize) at a time
    Write-Host "Writing to $LocalDir\$DirName\$LeafName"
    Do{
      $retval = $reader.GetBytes(4, $startIndex, $out, 0, $bufferSize);
      $startIndex += $bufferSize;

      $writer.Write($out, 0, $retval);
      $writer.Flush();
    }while ($retval -eq $bufferSize)
    #
    ## finish writing the file
    $writer.Close();
    $fs.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(txtdir.Text,DirName,LeafName);
Console.WriteLine("accessing " + fullPath);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: where would I insert this?  would I replace the the code that go the error?

Comment: If this persists, consider writing to the root of a drive `c:\` , or a location that you **know** you'll have permission to write to: i.e. My Documents, etc.

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Combine' takes '3' arguments

Comment: @Jeff: right. Sounds like .NET 3.5 won't take 3 args. Try cut to 2.

Comment: the only 2 that I could put in there are dirname and leafname.  I need to have the physical directory in there somehow.

Comment: I basically want to export the full path including the file to my local hard drive while maintaining the full path folder structure.